# PyGame: Proper use of Unicode

Tags: unicode, pygame

My goal is to create a program, with which the user can learn Bible verses by getting shown a problem and solving it through input (e.g. "Quote vers Gen 3:15"). As the Bible translation, I have to work with, is German, it contains a ton of umlauts, which are never showing properly.

My PyGame file's header:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Later on, I list the three German umlauts:

```
u'ö'.encode('utf-8')
u'ä'.encode('utf-8')
u'ü'.encode('utf-8')
```

The txt-file is parsed by this function:
   def load_list(listname):

```
fullname = os.path.join("daten", listname + ".txt")
with codecs.open(fullname, "r", "utf-8-sig") as name:
    lines = name.readlines()
for x in range(0, len(lines)):
    lines[x] = lines[x].strip("\n")
    lines[x] = lines[x].strip("\r")
print lines
```

I'm aware, that I could combine the two lines with the strip-commands, but that's not the topic here.

How can I get my PyGame to display the umlauts from the text-file correctly as well also display the user input's umlauts correctly? I checked hundreds of suggestions, I can't get anything really working here.

Any help is highly appreciated, before I lose my sane mind (well, as I'm sitting here, coding games, I probably did already anyway :D )

Comment: How is your game executed? Commandline? You probably need to encode the output before printing, matching the encoding of your terminal.

Comment: Anyway, the lines where you are encoding the umlaut letters (the second code block) doesn't do anything: they're just three strings that are not assigned to anything.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I honestly didn't understand the first one, sorry. Did you mean that I'm basically encoding the input from the file, which wouldn't make sense but rather should encode the output of the print as unicode?
I'm not sure of how to achieve it, but can I use something like:
print u'lines? or put it in the for loop and as print u'lines[x]?

Comment: Well, that's weird now o.O When I print a single line:
print lines[x]
It shows all unicode characters correctly, when I print the whole thing as a list:
print lines
then it shows those \x... codes again...

Comment: Seems I figured something out: The whole list of strings can't be properly "unicoded", even if I use unicode on a single string in the list, the list as such won't show properly if printed. Since I anyway need to print a single string from the list, it might not even be a problem in the end... Going back to experiment more...

Comment: ah I see. the `\xXX` sequences are no encoding issues. It's just the representation format (builtin `repr()`), which is called when you print a list. That's not quite intuitive. Concerning encoding of in- or output: you need to both: decode input (which happens by using `codecs.open()`), and encode the output (which you are not explicitely doing, but the terminal seems to be showing the correct characters, maybe by accident). Got it all? ^-^

Comment: Got this result:
As long as I only display a single string, it shows it correctly on all systems, even when blitted by pygame.font.render(...); but in a list of strings, it just does not show properly, even if I apply .encode("utf-8") to each element of the list... Anyway, my problem is solved and you really helped me a lot :) Maybe you make it all an answer I can mark as "accepted", so you get the credits?

Comment: I did. I'm still not sure what exactly you struggled with and what solved it, but I'm glad it helped.

Comment: I'm honestly neither sure what really solved the problem, but the umlauts are correctly blitted, even on my wife's Chinese system... So: never touch a running system :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll try to summarize:

- Printing something else than a string or unicode opject triggers that object's `__repr__()` method. If it is a sequence, this applies to the contained elements as well, causing any non-ascii character to be escaped with `\xXX` (or `\uXXXX`) notation. Note the difference between `print 'text'` and `print ['text']`: in the latter case, the string's quotes will be printed as well (besides the brackets of course). Use `str.join()` for concatenating lists of strings in order to control the way the output looks.
- It's a good idea to always explicitely decode input (as you do by using `codecs`) and encode the output (which is not done in the code snippets in your question).
- The source file encoding (the `# coding: utf8` line in the header) has nothing to do with encoding of input and output. It only enables you to type non-ascii character in string literals (= characters inside quotes in the source file), instead of using `\xXX` escapes.

Hope that makes some things clearer. There's a lot that can go wrong that looks like an encoding error, and it's not always easy to find out what's actually happening.

Comment: I have seriously no idea why it works to blit the umlauts in the code I posted up there. I just did something else, used the same way of (not) encoding the output and it just doesn't work there... Maybe better I write it all again... Anyway, I'd be very grateful for any tip of how to encode the output, I'm trying a lot right now, nothing seems to work... e.g. string.encode("utf-8") leads to the blitting of one "weird" character (the replacements for the umlauts) and any futher input of an umlaut leads to an out-of-range error of unicode...

Comment: Made it, thank you again :D Your remarks made me find the problem and finally solve it :)